# Anybody used capnproto js (capnp-js) library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, capnproto

Is there anybody using (or plan to use) [capnp-js-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capnp-js-plugin) and [capnp-js](https://github.com/capnp-js/serialization) modules for nodejs? 
I cloned these repos and ran the tests, but they fail. Also when I just install capnp-js (via npm), the generated js code has syntax errors even for a simple schema:

```
@0xec2f2fe5874ad874;

using Uid=Int32;

struct User {
    id @0 :Uid;
    name @1 :Text;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for the same info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anybody trying to use these modules, I would suggest to wait a bit, and avoid them for the moment. I have opened an issue (https://github.com/capnp-js/serialization/issues/17) and I got a reply from the owner of the module that I should better wait for the next major release, which will be a completely rewritten version.